# Partial view call not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jscript, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am getting this error

> Error:"0x80020101 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not
>   complete the operation due to error 80020101."

Function Call:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("_PartialView", "Controller")';
url += '/?Id='+@ViewBag.Id+'&param=0';
```

url is building as per the requirement, even the partial view is getting loaded after the error.

Comment: Can you show your javascript? BTW, could you not pass those parameters as an anon type rather than build a URL like that?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you append the Id and param manually? You can put it all together:

```
@Url.Action("_PartialView", "Controller", new { Id = ViewBag.Id, param = 0 })';
```